# PMF of two uniformly distributed breakpoints

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

**Question:**
A stick of length $L>0$ is broken at a uniformly random point X. Given that $X=x$, another breakpoint $Y$ is chosen uniformly on the interval $[0, x]$.
Find the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$.

**What I got:**

1. I know that $X \sim Unif(0, L)$, so $P(X=x) = \frac{1}{L}$.
2. Furthermore, we know that $Y|X=x \sim Unif(0, x)$. Therefore, $P(Y=y | X=x) = \frac{1}{x}$.
3. Using *Baym's rule* I get 
   $$P(Y=y, X=x) = P(Y=y | X=x) \cdot P(X=x) = \frac{1}{x \cdot L}$$
   for $x \in [y, L]$ and $y\in [0,x]$ and zero otherwise. [I edited the support]

The marginal distribution of $Y$ is therefore given by
\begin{align}
P(Y=y) &\equiv \int_y^Ldx \;P(Y=y, X=x) \\
&= \int_y^Ldx \;\frac{1}{x \cdot L} \\
&=\frac{\ln{(L)} - \ln{(y)}}{L}
\end{align}

Comment: Actually you are working with continuous random variables with uniform distribution, so it is not a pmf; instead it is a pdf, and thus you should not write something like $P(X = x)$ also (conditional part is ok). When you are integrating, you forgot the support you stated: $0 < y < x < L$. So the lower integration limit should be $y$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Thank you BGM. I ediremoved my main(!) mistake.